# Exclude an object during serialization with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm attempting to serialize an object but I would like to exclude one of the objects inside it.  I've tried `[NonSerialized]` and it is still attempting to serialize it when I call `XmlSerializer` on a Cart object.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Cart")]
public class Cart : ICart
{
    // Public Properties
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string ID { set; get; }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    [NonSerialized]
    public CartSerializer Serializer = new CartSerializer(this);
}
```

Comment: `XmlIgnore` should have done this (if you are using an XmlSerializer) - can you show your serialization code?

Comment: @BrokenGlass is right. Use `XmlIgnore`

Comment: Other option would be to make it private instead of public. . .

Comment: What makes you think it's being serialized?

Comment: Both `[NonSerialized]` and `[Serializable]` are not meaningful when using the Xml Serializer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may try to use XmlIgnore like this, it works!

```
    [XmlIgnore]  
    public string AnyProperty 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```